# Format currency for different countries

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms and I tried to format a string (in XAML view) for currency in form: `1.235.436,00` where comma `,` is the decimal separator. At first, I used `StringFormat{0:C2}` and result was: `$1,235,436.00` which is for US. After, I tried `StringFormat{0:#,0.#0}`, result: `1,235,436.00`.

At last, I tried to use same logic by swapping the dot and comma `{0:#.0,#0}`, and I got as result: `1235436.000`.

So how I can format for currency for France, Spain, Swedish, etc. 
which is `0.000.000,00 €/kr`?

XAML code:

```
Label Text="{Binding value, StringFormat='{0:C2}.'}"
```

Which is not correct in my case.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do that directly in the binding using `StringFormat`. You can either implement a custom `IValueConverter` or create a `string` property and then implement the formatting in code:

```
1235436.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES"));
```

This will format the number as a currency with specific Spanish culture display setting.

You can also modify the a default culture format to force a specific formatting:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
```

But you should not need to do this. The culture defaults are set in the way in which the users expect the content to be displayed. Changes in the default formats can cause misunderstandings.

Comment: Adding a custom property do not work when generating apk with linking. I'm puzzled

Answer (score 2):

The format `{0:C2}` that you used is the right one. To change the format based on the region, you need to change the culture on the thread. It looks like you have it set to the default `en-US` like you said. You can check it like this:

```
  CultureInfo current = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
  Console.WriteLine("The current culture is {0}", current.Name);
```

To change it to France:

```
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

And now your value will be automatically formatted like `1.235.436,00`.

Comment: Thank you for advice but in Xamarin Forms I can't use expression:  
`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");`

Comment: That's not an expression, you need to add it to your C# code. When you start your app, you need to detect the language and region of the user's phone, and then use the line from my answer to set the thread culture accordingly.

Comment: Thank you **Racil Hilan** and **Martin Zikmund** for suggestions :)

Here is the answer in Xamarin Forms:

`CultureInfo myCurrency = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
 CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = myCurrency;`

Comment: Yes, this is similar to my suggestion, only uses `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` instead of `CurrentCulture`. After you run this line of code, all formats (e.g. currency, dates, etc...) will be done using the specified culture.

Answer (score 1):

Add line the code in the xaml.cs This convert the culture

```
CultureInfo myCurrency = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = myCurrency;
```

In the xaml

```
<Label Text="{Binding value, StringFormat='{0:#,0.#0}'}"
```

Result: `5,245.00`

I get this information through a list

Answer (score 0):

you try to way:

```
// Get Present Culture in app.

var ci = new CultureInfo(App.DeviceCulture);
```

// Convert to format String.

```
stringValue = ConvertCultureCurrencyToString(stringValue, ci);
```

// Create method convert to format

```
public static string ConvertCultureCurrencyToString(string stringValue, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
                return "0";

            stringValue = System.Convert.ToString(stringValue, ci);
            // currency -> double (format to double)
            var currency = decimal.Parse(stringValue, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, ci);

            stringValue = currency.ToString("#,###.###", ci);

            if (stringValue.FirstOrDefault() == '.' || stringValue.FirstOrDefault() == ',')   
                stringValue = $"0{stringValue}";

            return stringValue;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "0";
        }

    }
```